# Complex queries, local computing vs database server

Tags: database, time

I was wondering, about one thing,

the amount of time, when executing queries at database server should be the shortest as possible, so what is better aproach, when creating information system?

Should we write some complex queries (joins on joins, having, group by, everything together), or rather use just basic crud operations, and simulate those demands localy at the system (local variables, loops and stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this situation myself. I could either output the entire chat with the admin GUI tools on my site visible to an admin, or have the local user perform that functionality. Since the local user could easily inspect element and see the admin tools then, it was better for it to be server-side. The way I think of it is if there is no security risk then make it local.